# How to apply the Builder pattern for nested objects

Tags: c#, builder

I used the `builder pattern` successfully in the past and it's very useful.

However, I have a group of nested object that goes down several levels.
[image: Attempt to use builder pattern with nested objects]

The problem is that, although I consider this understandable, it doesn't seem to be simplifying much.

And my question: Is there a simpler, better or more elegant way of applying the builder pattern to nested objects with 5 levels?

Would it be preferable to just instantiate the whole object?

Or would it be preferable to stop `building` on the step level?

Or just start `building` on the step level?

Comment: What is the problem? You don't like nesting? This is unavoidable, unless you make a builder which can attach parts for any level.

Comment: @Sinatr, I am not asking because a disliking of nesting or anything other than that the creation of the object above is not simplified by the builder pattern as it happens with less nested objects. That is all. I am now trying to find out if there are any better solution for this case or if I should go with a hybrid solution e.g. mixing with factories.

Comment: The builder patter **does** difference already. E.g. what if section builder `WithTitle` is required dozens of lines of code? You have just one line and it's clear. You can only eliminate *repeating* code, but I fail to see one. So you have to clearly express what you don't like, otherwise question is unclear. How can one offer something *better* if he don't know what is *bad*? To me, this code is just fine.

Comment: `The problem is that, although I consider this understandable, it doesn't seem to be simplifying much.` You may agree or not that this could be a problem but this *is* clear. I am going to wait for more feedback but in the meantime I am keeping my build pattern and moving on.